# Android shortcuts automatic deletion

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a application where I can press and hold and then create a shortcut of that particular deck/folder but when I delete the folder from the app itself, the icon(shortcut) stays there leading to a crash when taped upon. I placed a check for NPE so now its not crashing but I want to know if we can delete the shortcut on the folder deletion itself. Is there a way in Android Studio(kotlin). Below if the code to create that shortcut

```kotlin
    fun createIcon(context: Context, did: DeckId) {
        // This code should not be reachable with lower versions
        val shortcut = ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(this, did.toString())
            .setIntent(
                Intent(context, Reviewer::class.java)
                    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .putExtra("deckId", did)
            )
            .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(context, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setShortLabel(Decks.basename(col.decks.name(did)))
            .setLongLabel(col.decks.name(did))
            .build()
        try {
            val success = ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(this, shortcut, null)

            // User report: "success" is true even if Vivo does not have permission
            if (AdaptionUtil.isVivo) {
                showThemedToast(this, getString(R.string.create_shortcut_error_vivo), false)
            }
            if (!success) {
                showThemedToast(this, getString(R.string.create_shortcut_failed), false)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.w(e)
            showThemedToast(this, getString(R.string.create_shortcut_error, e.localizedMessage), false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where are you [disabling the shortcut](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts/managing-shortcuts#disable-shortcuts) once it becomes invalid?

Comment: @ianhanniballake disabling the shortcut method will remove the shortcut if the folder no longer exists?

Comment: Did you read the docs I linked?

Comment: Got my answer Thankyou! going through it

Answer (score 0):

```
 /** Disables the shortcut of the deck whose id is [did] */
fun disableDeckShortcut(did: DeckId) {
    val childDids = col.decks.childDids(did, col.decks.childMap()).map { it.toString() }
    val deckTreeDids = listOf(did.toString(), *childDids.toTypedArray())
    val errorMessage: CharSequence = getString(R.string.deck_shortcut_doesnt_exist)
    ShortcutManagerCompat.disableShortcuts(this, deckTreeDids, errorMessage)
}
```

Above is how I solved the issue if anyone wants to read the same in detail here is the [link](https://medium.com/@mailtoashish693/android-studio-in-app-shortcut-folder-shortcut-proper-implementation-ba1a13a83acb)